# Pass True task in camunda

Tags: java, workflow, activiti, camunda

I have some complex processes in **Camunda** and there is a receipt task at the end of all of them. In the receipt task, we show the summary of the process variables. The problem is that the receipt task is optional and it isn't a forced task for users so the user can quit the process without completing the receipt task. In this situation, the process instance's status stays in Active and this is causing our report a bad view.

Is there any solution for our goal?

I show an example process that has the format of all our processes. The first step is the data entry task that the user has to complete. The second is a service task that stores data in a DB for example and the final task is Receipt. Actually, I want the completing the process to be independent of the Receipt step, and after Store Data step the process will be completed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am missing something from the description of your workflow and your problem. If the "Receipt" task is optional, you basically need input from the users if they want to execute or skip it. Maybe you could just capture that information ahead in the "User Data Entry" task and skip the final task based on that variable. (In my suggestion of the workflow I assume the majority is not interested in a receipt.)
If that is not how you intend to offer the "Receipt" I'd need to know more details about it.

[image: BPMN process with gateway to skip Receipt]

Comment: Actually, I want to show the Receipt task to the user always but I need to complete that before showing the receipt form because users maybe don't complete that.

Comment: Ok, I don't know enough about how you are using Camunda. For example: are you integrating with a custom application or are you using the Camunda tasklist only? And I am still wondering, what is the actual task for a user in "Receipt"? More information may foster the right answers.
Some ideas: 
- end the process without the receipt task and control the display of the receipt in your application
- you could use a timer event to trigger completion after some time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your "receipt" task as it's own process (a single step process) and trigger it using a signal/message from the main process.
This way, the main process can complete, the receipt task is presented to the user butwhether they complete the task or not doesn't impact the main process.

Comment: is the new process(receipt) auto-completed or user must complete that?

Comment: Sam, that's up to you. You said you wanted the task to be optional but always presented. You can have it show up but signal it to close automagically on main process completion or any other event (signal or timer). I imagine you would need some mechanism to clean up "optional" tasks that may build up in a users task list.